# Load a partial page with class identifier

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to load content from a page hosted on another site.

The problem is that the target page doesn't has an ID, but a class name.

So I built a sample proxy in PHP to get the HTML content using `get_file_contents`.

But what to do next?

Example:

```
<body>
 <span class="news">NEWS FOR TODAY</span>
</body>
```

i want to get the content inside `.news`

Comment: What is the question?  What specifically do you want help with?

Comment: Are you trying to parse specific content out of the page that you have retrieved?  Your question still doesn't say what you are trying to achieve and what you want help with.  In your example web page, what do you want to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I did get you, you're probably trying to print out/load only part of returned string, in this case .news. Try following
in php

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents("http://your.news/news.php");
?>
```

and this in jquery

```
$("#test").load('get.php .news');
```

Try [working demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/a077f.php)

Comment: ('get.php .news'); this is an invalid url for PHP to use in `get_file_contents` , </news> was a typo :P

Comment: @Sourav: and what's your ajax response?

Comment: looking for the first '.hscope_subtitle'

Answer (score 1):

Why not flush everything to the client (JavaScript), where you parse using jQuery?

So in PHP:

```
print file_get_contents("...");
```

And in JavaScript:

```
$('...').load("proxy.php .news");
```

Comment: @Sourav: Since the remote server provides a class rather than an ID, aren't there multiple `.news` elements by any chance?

Comment: Yup it has, i want the first one's content only from  `http://shop.freehoroscopesastrology.com/leo_horoscope.asp`

Comment: looking for the first 'hscope_subtitle'

Comment: @Sourav: If `proxy.php` literally serves the contents of that webpage, `.load("proxy.php .hscope_subtitle")` should work.